# action mailer settings for dkim signing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, dkim

I am trying to understand what "config.after_initialize" is doing to my mailer.  I have emails being sent out via a rake task using a UserMailer class that I derived from Devise::Mailer.  When I use the following code the DKIM header is not there.  If I remove the after_initialize the DKIM headers work.  I'm guessing this is an order of initialization issue or I'm not setting all the settings for the mailer?  I'm not sure.  Can someone shed some light on this one or how I would start debugging it?

environments/production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.asset_host     = 'http://savethesparkles.com'

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'savethesparkles.com' }
  config.after_initialize do
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      port:                 587,
      domain:               'savethesparkles.com',
      user_name:            ENV['AWS_SES_USER'],
      password:             ENV['AWS_SES_PASS'],
      authentication:       :login,
      enable_starttls_auto: true
    }
  end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/user_helper"
include UserHelper

class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.                                               
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`                                                           

  default from: "Save The Sparkles <contact@savethesparkles.com>",
  reply_to: "contact@savethesparkles.com"

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out mostly what was going on. Removing the "config.after_initialize do" allowed the DKIM headers to be on the email messages so that started working. But only after I fixed the Authentication issue I was running into which had to do with my environment and it wasn't picking up the environment ses user and pass that I specified in /etc/environment. My rake tasks were picking up the environment vars but any authentication emails done in the Devise controllers were not picking up the environment vars.

My fix for my environment on an EC2 Ubuntu box was to switch some environment vars to .bash_profile.